# iOS In-App Purchases Multiple In-App Stores

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an App with 2 different Modes.
I want each Mode to have it's own store for In-App purchases.
I'm having a hard time find any policy information or info about having more than one In-App store inside the same App (that could be because it's not a problem at all).

If it's not okay to have "2" stores, would it be okay to have them be the same store and then just filter out the ones that shouldn't be available in that particular Mode?

Comment: Only Apple can answer questions about Apple policies with any kind of authority. So I don't think you'll get more than opinions here.

Having said that, I don't think Apple's developer guidelines contain anything about in-app stores. They talk about in-app purchases, and how you organize them in your app is pretty much up to you. Having a store is just a convenient way to do it, especially if you have many and/or dynamic IAPs. I have apps that don't have a store at all but contain a couple of IAPs that can be unlocked in certain places.

But again, this is just an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the mode to select which of two different sets of in-app purchases are shown to the user.  You are free to show or hide in-app purchases as you like, however be clear to the user about any previous purchases!

Answer (score 0):

You can show what ever you want in your shop, but all users should be able in a way or another to buy the same product otherwise it can be seen as discrimination in some countries and it's illegal.

If the in-app purchases are clear functionalities of one mode and the user choses which mode he uses then I don't think there is a problem. But if you force assign a mode to a specific user without him knowing or being able to do anything about then you can have problems, especially if the functionalities are different.

And for example, I worked for some companies which use tiers for consumable (if you already purchased the cheap package, the more expensive one are shown) and this was a problem of discrimination. The solution was allowing any customer to contact support to get access to lower (or higher) tiers. Then even if it's not in the shop they have the possibility to buy the IAP if they want to.